# Maven: My project has a dependency that is NOT in any maven repo (system scope). Does it get included in my final jar?

Tags: java, maven-2, maven, dependencies

So my maven project depends on a jar that is NOT in any maven repository. Therefore I need to use the system scope to include this local file in my maven classpath. Question is: When I build my final jar to distribute my library, I do need to somehow include that dependency with it. The classes can be extracted and then bundled with my library classes OR the jar can be included somehow inside my library jar. I am not even sure the latter (jar inside jar) is possible in Java.

So how should I approach this problem? Will Maven take my system scope dependency and take care of that for me? What should I do?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it will not. These dependencies are only for compilation and transitive dependency resolution. Your library consumers should have the jar too.
However, you could use the Assembly Plugin to repackage the jar's classes into your artifact.

Or, the standard approach: then you will publish your artifact, you will create a public repository for deployment. You also could deploy the jar in it.

**UDPATE:** adding example for the shade plugin (instead of the Assembly)

```
  <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
                <phase>package</phase>
                <goals>
                  <goal>shade</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                  <artifactSet>
                        <includes>
                          <include>legacy-jar.groupId:legacyJar</include>
                        </includes>
                  </artifactSet>
                </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
  </plugin>
```

Comment: Would you be so kind to tell me how can I use the Assembly Plugin to repackage the jar's classes into my artifact, so my customers will have everything they need when they include my jar in their projects?

Comment: I've updated my answer with the example using the Shade plugin however.

Comment: One more thing, Kan. Will that create a separate jar with everything, myproject-all.jar like I see over there, or will it just create a single myproject.jar with everything?

Comment: Single myproject.jar by default. However, could be configured differently.

Answer (score 1):

There is a second option. Put the jar into your repository as described here:

http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-local.html

and to your online repository

http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-remote.html

give your client access to your repository and use your legacy.jar as normal dependency.

It depends a little bit what kind of library do you have. With this way you don't have problems with version conflicts of your legacy.jar in the environment of your customer.

Comment: I don't want to setup any kind of repository. I want my client to have a jar and that jar to have everything it needs to run. What you said does not make sense, because the legacy jar will be always coupled with the library jar, in other words, at least for the customer one does not exist without the other.

Comment: Without your own repository the shade/assembly solution is the way to go... What I mean is that your jar is used together with other jars. This can happen if for example your component is used within a web application.

Answer (score 0):

Could this be what you are looking for, http://maven.40175.n5.nabble.com/How-to-specify-local-dependency-in-maven2-td103415.html.